How to copy artifacts from upstream project in Jenkins using "Copy artifacts plugin " when the downstream build is still Running?
I have a maven upstream Jenkins job which calls a downstream job and waits for the downstream job to complete . Down stream job has to copy maven artifacts (zip file) generated form the workspace of the upstream job .


in the image you can see my upstream job is "Blocked until the triggered projects finish their builds" and in the downstream job configurations I am trying to use which build - "upstream job that triggered this build" to copy artifacts . issue is downstream jobs plugin is unable to copy artifacts from the upstream job . I am assuming that it is unable to copy as the upstream job is not completed.
if I use which build - "**copy form the workspace of last completed build ** " it works fine. Any other option are not working.

But I want it to specifically copy form the upstream build that triggered the job because upstream job is triggered by code changes in bitbucket and I want to use the snapshot.zip that is build freshly as it has the code changes and I want to test those changes in  snapshot.zip.
How to achieve this .am I missing to set some configurations?? Any help would be appreciated.

What do you mean "unable to copy artifacts"? What's the error message?

I  don't see  any Error message in the log. My target directory is empty when I check. This concludes that artifact was not copied If  copying artifacts was  successful I see "Copied 1 artifact from "auto_val_copy_delete_me" build number 11" message, and I can see the artifact in my target directory. As I mentioned copying artifices is successful when i use "copy form the workspace of last completed build"

This is not going to work with the Freestyle jobs because they upload the artifacts in the Post-build Actions which run after the Build Steps (including any blocking downstream pipelines) are completed. Your options are:

Don't block the upstream pipeline. This will probably result in some re-architecture.
Upload artifacts to external storage, like AWS S3, and pass the url of the object to the downstream pipeline.
Switch the upstream job from Freestyle to pipelines and upload artifacts before triggering the downstream job.


Thanks for the Response, My upstream job is not a pipeline job, it is a maven job that builds maven project. I want my downstream job to copy the zip file generated in the upstream job, Also i want my upstream job to wait until all my downstream jobs  are build because i send out a email notification about the status of  my upstream job which depend on my downstream job .
Does your answer hold true even for maven project ??Because as i said i am able to copy the artifacts if which build option is set to - "copy form the workspace of last completed build" . for other options it doesn't work.

Maven and Freestyle are very similar in this regard - no artifacts are uploaded until the very end of the job. Accessing workspace of a running job is not supported by the Copy artifacts plugin because the plugin cannot guarantee that the files are not being changed as it tries to copy them.
